# Frame vs WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, browser, frame

If **all** I'm trying to do is display the contents of some web page in a WPF app, what are the pro's and cons of using the WebBrowser control versus the Frame control?   As I understand it Frame wraps WebBrowser anyway.

I have no need to display WPF in my control so that feature of Frame doesn't concern me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just wanting to display a webpage, I would use the **WebBrowser** control.  Even if it's only for the reason that the naming makes more sense and is easier to understand at a glance what the "frame" is for.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Frame' can display WPF content as children, and spin-up the IE ActiveX control only when 'web' content is displayed.  (Start by displaying your internal application help content or data content, then have a link to web page for additional details.)  I think if you're considering XAML static content(1) augmented by web content then Frame is the best choice.

1 - see [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx)